# Django - If user is a certain value display element

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I’m currently building a gaming app where a currently logged in user has access to play different games based on their rank in our application.

So if a currently logged in user has a rank of let’s say 100 than all the games rank 100 and below will be displayed. The rest of the games will be locked.

What would be the best way to achieve this?
How can i display unlocked games based on the logged in user’s rank?

The rank of each game is the `game_rank` field in the `Game_Info` model.

The rank of the currently logged in user is the `rank` field in the `User_Info` model.

My current HTML shows which games are locked and unlocked in general but nothing user specific.

Code is below. Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

`models.py`

```
class Game_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    game_rank = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    game_image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_covers', null=True, blank=True)
    locked_game = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    unlocked_game = models.BooleanField(default=0)

class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=1)    
    user_games_enabled = models.ManyToManyField(Game_Info, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'unlocked_game': True})
```

`home.html`

```
            {% for content in user_profile_games %}
            {% if content.locked_game == True %}

            <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                <div class="locked_game" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" /> 
                        <img class="lock-img" src={% static 'images/treasure-chest-closed-alt.png' %} />
                        <button class="level-up">Reach level {{ content.game_rank }} to unlock</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if content.unlocked_game == True %}

            <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                <div class="image-wrapper" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                    <span class="material-icons play_btn">play_circle_filled</span>
                    <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" />
                </div>
            </a>
            <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
```

`views.py`

```
def account_view_home(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.all()
    user = request.user

        
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games
       }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: Please share your view code too.

Comment: @VinitaSonakiya Sure. Just did. Thank you!

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907905/django-cannot-display-elements-based-on-field-value

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate each game with an 'unlocked_game' field based on the user's rank something like below:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField, F
user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
    user_unlocked_game=Case(
        When(game_rank__lte=F('user_profile_rank'), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

And use in template something like below:

```
{% if content.user_unlocked_game %}
<!-- unlocked games logic -->
{% else %}
<!-- locked games logic -->
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT**: Used `F` expression to get model column data

Comment: I'm getting `name 'user_profile_rank' is not defined`.. how do i fix this? thanks for responding!

Comment: i resolved the above error and now I'm getting this `The annotation 'unlocked_game' conflicts with a field on the model.` not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: then just change the name of that field in annotated query `user_unlocked_game` or something like this and use that field in a tempate

Comment: do i have to put that if statement inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes you have to if you want to display all games.

Comment: I made that update and also added ``user_profile_rank = User_Info.rank`` to ``views.py``... for some reason I don't see locked games..only unlocked games. Am I missing something else? @Hetvi

Comment: I've tested using `When(game_rank__lte=100, then=Value(True)),` and that works but when it comes to using the `When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True))`.. not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: try it like this `When(game_rank__lte=F('user_profile_rank'), then=Value(True))`.  You can import if F expression like this `from django.db.models import F`

Comment: Looks like I'm getting `Cannot resolve keyword user_profile_rank into field.`  Then it gives me choices of the fields in my `Game_Info` model. Those aren't the choices we need. How can we fix this to reflect the `rank` field in the `User_Info` model?

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907905/django-cannot-display-elements-based-on-field-value