# Django - Cannot Display Elements Based On Field Value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I’m currently building a gaming app where a currently logged in user has access to play different games based on their rank in our application.

So if a currently logged in user has a rank of let’s say 100 than all the games with a game rank of 100 and below will be displayed. The rest of the games will be locked.

I can’t get this currently fully to work with my code.

What do I need to change with my code?

If I test using `When(game_rank__lte=25, then=Value(True)),` that seems to work, I can see both locked and unlocked games based on the value of 25 and less.

But when I do `When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True)),` that doesn’t seem to work. All the games are unlocked and none are locked.

The rank of each game is the `game_rank` field in the `Game_Info` model.

The rank of the currently logged in user is the `rank` field in the `User_Info` model.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**models.py**

```
class Game_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    game_rank = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    game_image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_covers', null=True, blank=True)
    locked_game = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    unlocked_game = models.BooleanField(default=0)

class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=1)    
    user_games_enabled = models.ManyToManyField(Game_Info, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'unlocked_game': True})
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField, F, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

def account_view_home(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile_rank = User_Info.rank
    user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.all()
    user = request.user


    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        user_profile_rank = int(user_profile.rank)  


        user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
            user_unlocked_game=Case(
            When(game_rank__lte=Cast('game_rank', output_field=IntegerField()), then=Value(True)),
            default=Value(False),
            output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )


        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games,
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games
       }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
                {% for content in user_profile_games %}
                {% if content.user_unlocked_game %}
                <!-- unlocked games logic -->

                <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                    <div class="image-wrapper" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                        <span class="material-icons play_btn">play_circle_filled</span>
                        <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" />
                    </div>
                </a>
                <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

                {% else %}
                <!-- locked games logic -->

                <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                    <div class="locked_game" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" /> 
                            <img class="lock-img" src={% static 'images/treasure-chest-closed-alt.png' %} />
                            <button class="level-up">Reach level {{ content.game_rank }} to unlock</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of comparing the rank is conceptually correct but the problem you are facing is because of the following two reasons:

1. You are referring to the `rank` field of the `User_Info` model and not the instance of `User_Info`

FOllowing is the problematic part:

```
user_profile_rank = User_Info.rank
```

2. You are not casting the `CharField` fields to integer before comparison

In your views, make the following changes:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    user_profile_rank = int(user_profile.rank)  # Convert rank to integer

   
    user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
        user_unlocked_game=Case(
            When(game_rank__lte=Cast('game_rank', output_field=IntegerField()), then=Value(True)),
            default=Value(False),
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
    )
```

I hope it will solve the problem.

Comment: I currently get ``'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'rank'`` with that solution.  Do you know what else I can do to fix?

Comment: For testing if I change to ``user_profile_rank = int(User_Info.rank)`` i get ``int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'`` as well so I'm not sure what to do. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Doing `user_profile_rank = int(User_Info.rank)` is not correct because here you are converting the `User_Info` classes's `rank` field to int, which is not correct. 
Instead, take an instance of `User_info` class and then convert its `rank` value to int. Like I did in my proposed solution: 
`user_profile = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    user_profile_rank = int(user_profile.rank)`

Comment: ok cool, So I did your same exact solution and I get ``name 'Cast' is not defined
``Why am I getting this error?

Comment: This is probably because you are trying to access the `rank` attribute on a QuerySet object, which is a collection of database records, rather than on a single model instance. The probable solution is that you need to ensure that `user_profile` refers to a single instance of `User_Info` like `user_profile = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)`

Comment: Can please you show me by updating your solution? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I would suggest you to share your view code, then I can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Ok I just updated what I have to the original post and I currently get ``'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'rank'``. I appreciate it so much!

Comment: Follow
`def account_view_home(request):
    user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
            user_profile_rank = int(user_profile.rank) 
            user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
                user_unlocked_game=Case(
                    When(game_rank__lte=Cast('game_rank', output_field=IntegerField()), then=Value(True)),
                    default=Value(False),
                    output_field=BooleanField()
               ))`

Comment: so I added what you have and now I receive no errors but I see all the games unlocked the same as image #2 on my post. I don't see any locked games when they certain games should be locked.

Comment: Please use:’When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True)),

Comment: You're a ninja! It works now! I can see both locked and unlocked games! Thanks!! Sending positive vibes your way!

Answer (score 1):

As rank is a CharField, it may not be reading it as an integer, which is why passing 25 explicitly works but `UserInfo.rank` does not.

`user_profile_rank = User_Info.rank` should instead be `user_profile_rank = int(User_Info.rank)`

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: so I tried that and got the error ``int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'`` maybe another solution would work?

Comment: I also tested by changing the ``rank`` field to ``rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)`` and no luck.